# How do I correctly configure a wireless router that's connected to an ONT?

Tags: wireless-router, lan, home-networking, nat, fiber

My physical network setup is like this:
Fibre Optics from ISP > Splitter > PON Connector > ONT > From LAN1 of ONT to WAN on Wireless Router> Via Wi-Fi my other devices are connected

My ONT Model: TP-Link XN020-G3v

My wireless router model: TP-Link Archer D2

My ISP: BSNL FTTH

Now this setup works and I can access the internet, but there are some problems.

First, I'm not sure I correctly configured LAN settings on ONT and wireless router, which is needed for the wireless router to work correctly. I have assigned a permanent local IP for my wireless router in the ONT LAN settings.

Second, both ONT and wireless router have SPI firewall features and I disabled SPI on ONT, I have disabled IGMP snooping and proxy on ONT, left them enabled on the wireless router.

Third, NAT is enabled on both devices, if I disable NAT on ONT, internet works only on ONT but the wireless router goes offline, if I disable NAT only on the wireless router, it will of course no longer be accessible via local assigned IP and the internet goes offline yet again.

Fourth, my ISP does not know the optimal MTU value, so I used this [tool](http://www.letmecheck.it/mtu-test.php) to help me determine the value and set the same value on both the ONT and wireless router.

So I need help with these

1. Properly configuring LAN settings on both ONT and router
2. Fine-tuning features and options in both devices and to determine whether identical features should be enabled on both or just on one.
3. I am lost with removing the double NAT on my network
4. Even though I used the tool to determine optimal MTU value, it still does cause loading issues for certain sites.

**ONT Internet Settings**
https://i.ibb.co/R2ST2cS/ONT-Internet-Settings.png

**ONT LAN Settings**
https://i.ibb.co/myzK6Wt/ONT-LAN-Settings.png

**ONT Security Settings**
https://i.ibb.co/1mQ684X/ONT-Security-Settings.png

**Router Internet Settings**
https://i.ibb.co/JshvGd8/Router-Internet-Settings.png

**Router LAN Settings**
https://i.ibb.co/823nLCF/Router-LAN-Settings.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That ONT is way more than just an ONT. It's a multifunction home gateway router (Wi-Fi AP, VoIP ATA, NAT gateway, DHCP server, etc) that just happens to have a PON port as its WAN port (that is, it has a built-in ONT on the WAN side).

The fact that the ONT's Internet settings ask for an Access Concentrator name, and doesn't default to a 1500 byte MTU, suggests that it's using PPPoE. Most PPPoE connections don't support Ethernet bridging, which means you have to keep NAT enabled on a box that does PPPoE.

You might be able to disable NAT and PPPoE on the ONT somewhere, so that it's transparently bridging between PON and LAN, but then you'll probably need to configure your D2 router to do PPPoE on its WAN port.

Comment: Yes, my ISP is indeed implementing PPPoE. I can indeed create a fresh WAN interface with bridge mode as connection type, but I wouldn't know how to handle configuration on D2 router. Plus, I think my LAN config on both devices are incorrectly configured. I'd appreciate any help man. Also, the ONT's MAC address is manually registered on my ISP's OLT.

Comment: On the D2's Internet Settings page, where you have the "Connection Type:" set to "Dynamic IP" right now, that probably really means "DHCP client". See if that pop-up menu lets you select PPPoE instead. The config I'm suggesting would mean the PPPoE packets would be coming from the D2's MAC address, not the ONT. So you might need to check with your ISP to see if you can register your D2's MAC address with them.